# Set metadata using Amazon S3 Transfer Utility for iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I can't find a way to set metadata using this library: [Amazon S3 Transfer Utility for iOS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transferutility.html)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`- setValue:forRequestParameter:`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3TransferUtilityExpression.html#//api/name/setValue:forRequestParameter:) on `AWSS3TransferUtilityExpression` to add metadata.

Note Amazon S3 stores user-defined metadata in lowercase. Each name, value pair must conform to US-ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

> You can assign user-defined metadata to an object. User-defined metadata must begin with the prefix "x-amz-meta-", otherwise Amazon S3 will not set the key value pair as you define it. You define custom metadata by adding a name that you choose to the x-amz-meta- key. This creates a custom key. For example, if you add the custom name alt-name, the metadata key would be x-amz-meta-alt-name.

You can refer this link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-metadata.html#add-object-metadata-user-defined

```
  var uploadCompletion: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
    uploadCompletion = { (uploadTask, error) in
        if error == nil {
            completion(nil)
        } else {
            completion(error)
        }
    }

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
//YOUR METADATA HERE
    expression.setValue("value", forRequestParameter: "x-amz-meta-yourkeyhere")

    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
    transferUtility.uploadData(data,
                               bucket: s3BucketName,
                               key: key,
                               contentType: "image/png",
                               expression: expression,
                               completionHandler: uploadCompletion)
```